# Minix 3.3 error code 12 file too big

Tags: minix

I need to get to `/usr/src/kernel/system.c` file, but when I try to open and modify it I get a message:

> File too big. Error code 12.

How can I handle it?

Comment: Still trying to use `mined` under MINIX 2? Then you need to use `elle`(which should have the same assigned keys as `mined`) or `Elvis`, a clone of `vi`: both are able to co-ope with large file, unlike `mined`.

Under MINIX3, the most usual reason is that you are short of disk space when running as `root`.

Comment: I've already managed to open it with vi, however your answer helped me understand what was the reason of my problem :) thanks